# foreach loop not working with regex

Tags: php, regex

My file `images.html` contains multiple lines with the following code:

```
<linestart><urlstart>http://...image.jpg<urlend><idstart>1<idend><lineend>
```

I want to parse the file but I can’t figure out my error.

My PHP code:

```
$pattern = "/<linestart>(.*?)<lineend>/s";
$html = file_get_contents('images.html');

$check = preg_match_all($pattern,$html,$match);

foreach($match[1] as $line)
{ 
$pattern2 = "/<urlstart>(.*?)<urlend>/s";
$check2 = preg_match_all($pattern2,$line,$match_url);

$pattern3 = "/<idstart>(.*?)<idend>/s";
$check3 = preg_match_all($pattern3,$line,$match_id);


echo $match_url." id= ".$match_id."<br>";
}
```

My result is:

> `Array id= Array`
>   `Array id= Array`
>   `Array id= Array`
>   `Array id= Array`
>   `Array id= Array`
>   `Array id= Array`

Any ideas why?

Comment: What are you expecting? `$match_url` and `$match_id` are arrays of all the matches. You need to loop over them, like you do with `$match`.

Comment: Can you have more than one `<urlstart>` or `<idstart>` in each `<linestart>` block? If not, you could use `preg_match` instead of `preg_match_all`.

Comment: each line only has 1 <urlstart>. I tried preg_match instead of preg_match_all.. same result.   the result should be URL and the the ID  (1 result per line)

Comment: You still need to subscript the match to get the capture group.

Comment: Barnmar... I don't understand what that means...  "subscript to capture the group" ?

Comment: Capture groups are the `(...)` expressions in the regular expression. `$match[1]` is the first group, `$match[2]` is the second, and so on.

Comment: What you put inside your HTML is not actually valid HTML at all, what's the deal? :)

Comment: That's not html... that's more like XML. You should probably be using DOM operations instead of trying to get a regex to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can match everything in one pattern:

```
$pattern = "/<linestart>.*?<urlstart>(.*?)<urlend>.*?<idstart>(.*?)<idend>.*?<lineend>/s";
$html = file_get_contents('images.html');

$check = preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
    echo $match[1] . " id=" . $match[2];
}
```